# Strange behaviour with ES5 filter in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I am trying to filter the data below using ES5 : filter.

```
{
        "EmailAddress": "joe@example.com",
        "Name": "",
        "Date": "2009-01-23 06:22:00",
        "State": "Active",
        "CustomFields": [
            {
                "Key": "[FirstName1]",
                "Value": "joe"
            },
            {
                "Key": "[LastName1]",
                "Value": "bloggs"
            }
        ]
}
```

To get the first Name , I tried the following code:

```
const firstName = subscriber.CustomFields.filter(cf => cf.Key='FirstName1')
```

But , after that line of code , the source is changed to ( see LastName1 changed to FirstName1 )  :

```
{
        "EmailAddress": "joe@example.com",
        "Name": "",
        "Date": "2009-01-23 06:22:00",
        "State": "Active",
        "CustomFields": [
            {
                "Key": "[FirstName1]",
                "Value": "joe"
            },
            {
                "Key": "[FirstName1]",
                "Value": "bloggs"
            }
        ]
}
```

I don't understand how extracting data through a filter can change the source. Am I overlooking something fundamental here?

Comment: It should be `cf.Key === 'FirstName1'` not `cf.Key='FirstName1'`

Comment: What do you mean by "the source is changed"? Surely it didn't change the source code file, did it?

Comment: Yes @Bergi - an assignment ( single =  , as opposed to double == ) will change the data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `==` instead assignment (`=`).

```
const firstName = subscriber.CustomFields.filter(cf => cf.Key == 'FirstName1')
```

```js
let subscriber = { "EmailAddress": "joe@example.com", "Name": "", "Date": "2009-01-23 06:22:00", "State": "Active", "CustomFields": [ { "Key": "[FirstName1]", "Value": "joe" }, { "Key": "[LastName1]", "Value": "bloggs" } ] }

const firstName = subscriber.CustomFields.filter(cf => cf.Key == '[FirstName1]');
console.log(firstName);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can't believe I didn't see that!